# Fulfilling order of seaport-js via WalletConnect returns 'invalid hash' error but the transaction goes through

Tags: ethereum, web3js, ethers.js, wallet-connect

I'm implementing an NFT swapping function with `seaport-js`. Eliminating gas related issues and under the same conditions, I have no problem swapping (fulfill order) via MetaMask(`window.ethereum`) but when I use WalletConnect the error below is returned, although the transaction actually goes through on the blockchain:

Goerli

```
Error: invalid hash (argument="value", value={"type":2,"chainId":5,"nonce":36,"maxPriorityFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x3b9aca00"},"maxFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x11b1f3f800"},"gasPrice":null,"gasLimit":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x02d873"},"to":"0x00000000006c3852cbEf3e08E8dF289169EdE581","value":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x00"},"data":"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","accessList":[],"hash":"0x18af833152c52860c2ace90f74badc966bfee7933ec0d8f4a3bf412ecee1c18b","v":0,"r":"0xbfed28e916aef948357dde16278a91afa777aba4bf3406250f4df792b4455a4d","s":"0x368a6113830320b128fbd336c39ef1c4288f119ba23ec6b97e93c31b6429df4e","from":"0x9cE9Bf1D83D5Fe99916Bf640A3615DB5e4A89fF0","confirmations":0}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=providers/5.7.2)
at Logger.makeError (index.js:224:1)
    at Logger.throwError (index.js:233:1)
    at Logger.throwArgumentError (index.js:236:1)
    at Formatter.hex (formatter.js:175:1)
    at Formatter.hash (formatter.js:222:1)
    at Web3Provider.eval (base-provider.js:1659:30)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (base-provider.js:5:43)
```

Mainnet

```
Error: invalid hash (argument="value", value=[178,249,79,137,31,184,161,230,15,112,195,90,10,54,215,71,155,251,31,175,58,52,149,33,57,141,86,152,68,61,160,247], code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=providers/5.7.2)
    at Logger.makeError (index.js:224:1)
    at Logger.throwError (index.js:233:1)
    at Logger.throwArgumentError (index.js:236:1)
    at Formatter.hex (formatter.js:175:1)
    at Formatter.hash (formatter.js:222:1)
    at Web3Provider.eval (base-provider.js:1659:30)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (base-provider.js:5:43)
```

The error code being `INVALID_ARGUMENT`, occurs in some hash validation function of ethers', where the argument is supposed to be a string but as you see from the error above it is a `PopulatedTransaction` object of seaport's. And this only happens when WalletConnect is used.

Here is the seaport implementation:

```
import { OrderComponents, OrderWithCounter } from "@opensea/seaport-js/lib/types";
import { ethers, providers } from "ethers";
import EthereumProvider from "@walletconnect/ethereum-provider";

export const fulfillSwapBySeaport = async (
  swapSignature: string,
  swapParameters: OrderComponents,
  ethereumProvider: providers.ExternalProvider | EthereumProvider
): Promise<string | null> => {
  try {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereumProvider);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    const account = await provider.listAccounts();
    const fulfiller = account[0];
    const seaport: Seaport = new Seaport(signer);
    const { executeAllActions: executeAllFulfillActions } =
      await seaport.fulfillOrder({
        order: {
          parameters: swapParameters,
          signature: swapSignature,
        },
        accountAddress: fulfiller,
      });
    const transaction = await executeAllFulfillActions();
    await transaction.wait(1);
    return transaction.hash;
  } catch (e: any) {
    console.log(e);
    return null;
  }
};
```